# UK comic strip from the 1970's

Tags: story-identification, comics

Looking for UK comic strip from 1970's, family visiting Russia shrunk to toy size hunted by KGB agents who think they are spies, they travelled in toy gypsy caravan pulled by 2 puppies.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.